# trigger click on id inside a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers, click

I'm trying to trigger a click on a id named click once the page loads. My script works fine when I manually click on the divs with the id click however I need the first element with id click to be clicked once the page loads.

HTML:

```
<ul><li><div id="click"></div></li></ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("div[id='click']").click(function() { alert("click detected!"); });
```

and this is what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("div[id='click']:eq(1)").click(); });
```

Comment: **Note:** ID's must be unique, use class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use trigger()

```
$('#click').on('click', function() { 
    alert("click detected!"); 
}).trigger('click');
```

Note that there is no "first element with the ID click", there is ***ONLY ONE*** element with that ID, as ID's are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$("#click").click(function() { alert("click detected!"); });
```